# Multiplication of two variables containing tuples in BASH script

Tags: bash, awk, tuples, multiplication

I have two variables containing tuples of same length generated from a PostgreSQL database and several successful follow on calculations, which I would like to multiply to generate a third variable containing the answer tuple. Each tuple contains 100 numeric records. Variable 1 is called *rev_p_client_pa* and variable 2 is called *lawnp_p_client*. I tried the following which gives me a third tuple but the answer rows are not calculated correctly:

rev_p_client_pa data is:

```
0.018183
0.0202814
0.013676
0.0134083
0.0108168
0.014197
0.0202814
```

lawn_p_client data is:

```
52.17
45
30.43
50
40
35
50
```

The command I used in the script:

```
awk -v var3="$rev_p_client_pa" 'BEGIN{print var3}' | awk -v var4="$lawnp_p_client" -F ',' '{print $(1)*var4}'
```

The command gives the following output:

```
0.948607
1.05808
0.713477
0.699511
0.564312
0.740657
1.05808
```

However when manually calculated in libreoffice calc i get:

```
0.94860711
0.912663
0.41616068
0.670415
0.432672
0.496895
1.01407
```

I used this awk structure to multiply a tuple variable with numeric value variable in a previous calculation and it calculated correctly. Does someone know how the correct awk statement should be written or maybe you have some other ideas that might be useful? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show small set of sample input data, and the required output from same inputs. Generally, you only need 1 invocation of `awk` and I don't see anything here that indicates a need to run `awk` twice. Good luck.

Comment: Please check who to create good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can pass multiple variable in a single invocation.   as asuggested by @shelter above. 

`echo "1" |awk -v val1="Hello!," -v val2="World"  '{print val1 " " val2}'`

Comment: Digvijay S: Thanks for your reply. I tried your recommendation. But it does not work. i only get a single value.

Comment: Sorry shelter, I got interrupted yesterday. I have provided some additional information.

Comment: `bash` doesn’t have any concept of a tuple. Could you clarify what you have and want please?

Comment: a ++ to you for including your sample data. (still too mucn). anyway ;-) (I didn't donwvote, but whoever did probably won't be back to reassess your Q). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [paste](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) to join the two data sets together, forming a list of pairs, each separated by tab.
Then pipe the result to `awk` to multiply each pair of numbers, resulting in a list of products.

```
#!/bin/bash

rev_p_client_pa='0.018183
0.0202814
0.013676
0.0134083
0.0108168
0.014197
0.0202814'

lawn_p_client='52.17
45
30.43
50
40
35
50'

paste <(echo "$rev_p_client_pa") <(echo "$lawn_p_client") | awk '{print $1*$2}'
```

Output:

```
0.948607
0.912663
0.416161
0.670415
0.432672
0.496895
1.01407
```

Answer (score 2):

All awk:

```
$ awk -v rev_p_client_pa="$rev_p_client_pa" \
      -v lawn_p_client="$lawn_p_client" '        # "tuples" in as vars
BEGIN {
    split(lawn_p_client,l,/\n/)                  # split the "tuples" by \n
    n=split(rev_p_client_pa,r,/\n/)              # get count of the other
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)                            # loop the elements
        print r[i]*l[i]                          # multiply and output
}'
```

Output:

```
0.948607
0.912663
0.416161
0.670415
0.432672
0.496895
1.01407
```